# Pancake Sort in python, and empty max() error message

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

`pancake_sort` sorts some numbers in descending order (flips the biggest number to top (end) of the array then back to the bottom), then prints the index at which it did that (+1). This means that the array `[4,3,2,1,5]` will flip from index 0 so that it becomes `[5,1,2,3,4]` and will print 1, then will flip from the index 1 and will become `[5,4,3,2,1]`, and it will print 2. Once it has done all its flips, it should then print 0. I've tried to add the different parts of the arrays together (the part that flips and the part that stays the same), but it doesn't work. I get this output and error message:

```
1 
1 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/khadijah/Documents/pypan.py", line 32, in <module>
    pancake_sort(arr)
  File "/Users/khadijah/Documents/pypan.py", line 19, in pancake_sort
    mi = arr.index(max(arr[i:arr_len]))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

I know that it has something to do with the `i` in the `mi` value, but I think I need that there so that it only checks the numbers between `i` and `arr_len`. Using `arr_len-1` doesn't work either. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
def pancake_sort(arr):
    arr_len=len(arr)
    i=0
    for i in range(0,arr_len-1):
        mi = arr.index(max(arr[i:arr_len]))
        arr = arr[0:mi-1]+arr[mi::-1]
        print()
        if mi == arr_len-1:
            print("1", end = " ")
        else: print(mi+1, end = " ")
        if i==0:
            arr=arr[::-1]
        else:
            arr = arr[0:i-1]+arr[i::-1]
    return arr

arr = [4,3,2,1,5]
pancake_sort(arr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subscript assignment with reversed() to "flip" the pancake:

```
def flipSort(A):
    for i in range(len(A)-1):
        p = A[i:].index(max(A[i:])) + i # index of max (to end)
        if i==p: continue               # nothing to flip, skip
        A[i:p+1]=reversed(A[i:p+1])     # <-- here is how to flip a subrange
        print(i+1,end=" ")              # print index (why one-based?)
    print("0")
```

output:

```
A = [4,3,2,1,5]
flipSort(A)
1 2 0
print(A)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: This almost works exactly! For smaller arrays, it seems to work, but some of my arrays are just larger than 100 elements. It ends up giving me 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8....all the way up to 100 0. Why do you think that is?

Comment: That depends on the content of the array.  If the array is randomized with few increasing-decreasing streaks, you will be more likely to swap at every index (or at most of them).  The larger the array, the higher the probability of flips in the low indexes. This is why this sort algorithm isn't used in the real world.

Comment: For example, if your array has distinct 500 random elements,  on the first index, you have 499/500 chances to need a flip, on the second index 498/499, on the third index 497/498, ... 2/3, 1/2.   In short you have roughly 80% chance to go all the way to the last index

Comment: this makes sense! thank you for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

you can use is :

```
def pancake_sort(arr):
    cur = len(arr)
    while cur > 1:
        # Find the maximum number in arr
        mi = arr.index(max(arr[0:cur]))
        # Reverse from 0 to mi
        arr = arr[mi::-1] + arr[mi + 1 : len(arr)]
        # Reverse whole list
        arr = arr[cur - 1 :: -1] + arr[cur : len(arr)]
        cur -= 1
        print(cur)
    return arr

print(pancake_sort([4,3,2,1,5]))
```

Comment: no, unfortunately, because this is in ascending order and outputs the wrong values for where it flips from. thank you, though!